# How to implement my own mysql server interface?

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, proxy, database-administration

Is it possible to implement mysql server interface and define my own logic for custom responding on SQL queries?

Some proprietary visualization tool supports connecting to mysql only. But my DB is not mysql but have jdbc driver. How to setup some kind of jdbc proxy that makes possible to connect to any non mysql DB ostensibly it is mysql with assumption SQL dialect differences is not a problem.

Comment: SQL Server offers Linked Servers, by which you can usa tables in a MySQL database from queries on the SQL server database. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017 MySQL has a FEDERATED storage engine, but it only connects MySQL - to - MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MariaDB's connect engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connect-jdbc-table-type-accessing-tables-from-another-dbms/) to create a table accessible via MySQL protocol that is really a JDBC connection.